# How to change Error color and underline color on input focus using material-ui v1.0.0-beta.40

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am using Material-UI `v1.0.0-beta.40` and I want to change the border color and error text color.

How can this be done?

Comment: Please provide an example code. And output snap if possible.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan Thanks but its my general question how can we change underline border color on input focus using beta version of material  ui

Comment: @Anil Ooh, I'm seeing you are asking for version 1 beta I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 7):

One of the ways to do it is inside of MuiTheme

```
import { createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides:{
        MuiInput: {
            underline: {
                    '&:after': {
                      backgroundColor: 'any_color_hex',
                    }
              },
        },
    }
});
export default myTheme;
```

and then import it into your component and use:

```
import {MuiThemeProvider} from 'material-ui/styles';
import myTheme from './components/myTheme'

<MuiThemeProvider theme = {myTheme}>
<TextField />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish that by using `errorStyle` attribute

> errorStyle The style object to use to override error styles

**Version 0.20.0**

```
   <TextField
      hintText="Hint Text"
        errorText="This field is required"
        errorStyle={{color: 'green'}}
    />
```

Working Demo

[image: Edit 31x89m1k1p]

**Version 1.0.0 beta**

```
const styles = theme => ({

  greenLabel: {
    color: '#4CAF50',
  },
  greenUnderline: {
    '&:before': {
      backgroundColor: '#4CAF50',    
    },
  },
  greenUnderline: {
    '&:after': {
      backgroundColor: '#4CAF50',
    },
  },

});


<FormControl >
  <InputLabel style={{color: 'green'}} htmlFor="name-simple">Error</InputLabel>
  <Input classes={{ inkbar: classes.greenInkbar, underline: classes.greenUnderline }} id="name-simple" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
</FormControl>
```

[image: Edit koyx2k78kv]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution based on most recent changes by material-ui v1. Hope It's help

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const inputBoxTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides:{
        MuiInput: {
            underline: {
                 '&:after': {
                    borderBottom: '2px solid #fff',
                  },
                  "&:after": {
                    borderBottom: '2px solid #fff',
                  }
              },
        },
    }
});
export default inputBoxTheme;

import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import inputBoxTheme from './theme/inputBoxTheme'

<MuiThemeProvider theme = {inputBoxTheme}>
  <TextField />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

An override isn't necessary to change the error color globally. It can be defined wherever you define your global colors / theme elements. For example:

```
import createMuiTheme from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';

export default createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
          main: '#FFFFFF',
        },
        secondary: {
          main: '#6200EE',
        },
        error: {
          main: '#D0180B',
        },
    },
});
```